# What are the performance bottlenecks for updating the data in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a [`LineChart`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/LineChart.java) with a single data set (usually 512 points). I need to replace the current data with new data and redraw the chart as quickly as possible, changing nothing else.

I am trying to understand the way the library works in order to optimise the update of the chart.

If I were to update the data set as follows:

```
lineDataSet.setValues(newEntries); // newEntries is List<Entry> w/new data
chart.invalidate(); //what are the intermediate steps here
```

it is not clear what intermediate steps are invoked and if they incur a performance cost. What are the performance bottlenecks in updating the chart like this? Can I overcome them by multithreading?

Comment: Thanks. See updated question.

Comment: Okay I think it's specific enough to attempt an answer now

Answer (score 2):

Start by having a look at the [`DataSet`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/DataSet.java) and `BaseDataSet` classes in the MPAndroidChart source.

The `DataSet` is backed by a simple list of `Entry`. Note also that MPAndroidChart needs to know the `xMin`, `xMax`, `yMin` and `yMax` for its own internal calculations and these are encapsulated in the `DataSet` object.

Every time you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` the min/max are recalculated inside the `DataSet` object which involves iterating over the entire backing list of `Entry`. Moreover, adding an unordered `Entry` will trigger iteration of the backing list to find the correct position in the list. Removal of an `Entry` will likewise trigger iteration of the backing list. In short, the `DataSet` object is optimised for adding ordered `Entry` only.

If you suspect that creation of new `DataSet` objects with 512 `Entry` is a bottleneck and could be optimised by offloading to another thread, I suggest you write a [microbenchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) to check the time taken for recreating the `DataSet` object and adding the `Entry` you want. While new object allocation in Android is expensive, the actual iteration of the `Entry` list in order to calculate the min/max is unlikely to be expensive because of CPU caching and spatial locality. If you want to make the case for offloading the construction of the new `DataSet` object to a new thread (using, say, an `AsyncTask`) you would have to prove in your benchmark that the overhead from offloading to another thread is small enough to justify your efforts.

Once you have called `mChart.setData(newDataSet)` then there is very little opportunity for multithreading without making extensive modification to the library. You can see the flow of control for yourself: `setData` triggers calculation of offsets and preparing matrices. Calculating the offsets is simple floating point addition (inexpensive), the transformation matrices are handled using native C++ code (already optimised).

When the `View` is drawn, the code in `onDraw()` must necessarily be executed on the main/UI thread. Although all this may seem sub-optimal, MPAndroidChart still manages to achieve a high level of performance in comparison to other charting libraries as can be seen in [this blog post](https://www.scichart.com/android-chart-performance-comparison/). You can see for yourself what frame rate you are achieving by calling `mChart.setLogEnabled(true)` and inspecting the logcat for the frame rate.

If you are unsatisfied with the frame rate you are getting, you could consider [SciChart](https://www.scichart.com/) which has better performance. Do note, however, that there is a licensing cost for the same. The tl;dr from this is there is only a little space for optimisation in MPAndroidChart as it stands and if performance is a requirement you may have to look to another library.

Comment: Thanks for the insight into the code. As I mentioned, I'm not concerned with recalculating the min and max data values: The axis calibrations are fixed and I don't want to change them. I just want to stuff new data points in there and redraw the line, come what may :-) That being the case I thought that perhaps my 2-line solution would save some time. I'm about to test it.

Comment: @RobertLewis since you won't be needing the recalculation of the min/max perhaps you can fork the library and remove that logic. I imagine you would get a small speedup there. You'd probably have to set the min/max manually yourself via mutators. If you get any results you are welcome to post them as a self-answer, I am sure people will be interested.